# Crystal Report XI: calculate subtotal % of total

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that calculates a summary field by group location which I am calling a sub total. There is another summary field by company in group company section. We allocate corporate overhead costs based on volume of revenue. I need to take the location total revenue and divide by the overall company revenue to get the % of volume. My problem is that I cannot get the company total into the location group row without effecting the numbers. I have tried to create a running total field to get the total. I have tried referring to the main report to get the company total and I have tried summarizing the location totals but I cannot summarize a summarized field. Any suggestions would be really helpful, thank you!

Company Locations----------  Total Revenue-------- % of Volume

California------------------------         500,000-----------------        500,000/950,000 ?

New York          ---------------------- 300,000

Ohio     ----------------------------          150,000

Company Total:   --------------  950,000

This looks like the same thing I am trying to do but I don't understand the answer yet..
http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27749404/Crystal-Reports-XI-fixed-value-for-denominator.html

Comment: is the company total a running total? what kind of fields are your total revenue: summary, running totals or formulas?

Comment: The company total isn't technically a running total; however when I add it to a field within my location group it acts like one so that each row is added to the previous row. This is what I meant by it throwing off the numbers when I try to use it in my location group section. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to share a value between reports and where the value would not be effected by which group it was in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your best option is creating a subreport on the report header to calculate only your total revenue and then using it on your main report through a shared variable.

Comment: In my case, I have a main report and sub report in place. I need the total by company within a calculation on the sub report. I am using a shared variable from my main report to my sub report, but it isn't working like I expected/intended. It doesn't look like I can insert a sub report into my sub report. For your suggestion, are you saying I should add a sub report to main report header and then share that to my sub report? Thanks!!

Comment: yup, add a subreport in your report header and calculate your total revenue there and using a shared variable pass it from that subreport to your main report and then to the other subreport you have to use it. PS: you cannot insert a subreport inside another subreport so use it as your last resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
if sum({totalRevenue},{location}) > 0 then
sum({totalRevenue},{location})
/
sum({totalRevenue})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My totalRevenue field is a very complicated summary field based off of a lot of variables. For that reason, I can't summarize it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to share a value between reports and where the value would not be effected by which group it was in?